# How does this appendToTail() method work in a singly linked list?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

Recently, when working through some coding interview questions I started to wonder how the following code actually works:

```
public static ListNode appendToTail (ListNode head, int valueOfNodeToAdd)
    {
        ListNode traveller = head;
        while (traveller.next != null)
        {
            traveller = traveller.next;
        }
        traveller.next = new ListNode(valueOfNodeToAdd);

        return traveller;
    }
```

When called, the method acts as expected and will traverse the list until it reaches the final ListNode, where it will then set the *next* property to the ListNode to be appended. I guess the question I have is how is the HEAD of the list not lost when this method is called? If you step through the code, it seems like a linked list with only two nodes should be returned. I recreated the problem in my IDE and stepped through it with the debugger, but it still seems unclear. I'll post the full context of my code below in case I'm missing something to consider. Thanks for the help!

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode resultHEAD = new ListNode();
        ListNode pointer1 = l1;
        ListNode pointer2 = l2;

        if (l1 == null)
            return l2;
        else if (l2 == null)
            return l1;

        while (pointer1 != null && pointer2 != null)
        {
            if (pointer1.val < pointer2.val)
            {
                appendToTail(resultHEAD, pointer1.val);
                pointer1 = pointer1.next;
            }
            else if (pointer1.val > pointer2.val)
            {
                appendToTail(resultHEAD, pointer2.val);
                pointer2 = pointer2.next;
            }
            else
            {
                // Arbitrarily select from l1
                appendToTail(resultHEAD, pointer1.val);
                pointer1 = pointer1.next;
            }
        }

        // Check which list is empty and append the rest of that list
        if (pointer1 != null)
        {
            while(pointer1 != null)
            {
                appendToTail(resultHEAD, pointer1.val);
                pointer1 = pointer1.next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while(pointer2 != null)
            {
                appendToTail(resultHEAD, pointer2.val);
                pointer2 = pointer2.next;
            }
        }

        return resultHEAD.next;
    }

    public ListNode appendToTail (ListNode head, int valueOfNodeToAdd)
    {
        ListNode traveller = head;
        while (traveller.next != null)
        {
            traveller = traveller.next;
        }
        traveller.next = new ListNode(valueOfNodeToAdd);

        return traveller;

    }
}
```

Comment: Calling the method mutates (changes) the list by adding a new node at the tail. But there's no reason the caller loses the head.  Local variables in the calling method are unaffected by the called one.  `appendToTail` is returning a reference to the second-last item in the list, but the calling code ignores that.

Comment: Note that you don't need to call `AppendToTail` using the real head of the list. You could call it with any element in the list, since it will find the same tail (and possibly sooner than starting at the beginning). For example, you could call it with the node returned by the previous call, which would reduce the time it take so get to the end of the list to a constant value.  (Although I don't understand why the function returns `traveller` and not `traveller. next`)